# Debug SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

## Problem

Every three days or so my Windows 8.1 CPU blue screens with the following message:

```
SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
AsusTP.sys
```

Usually it then restarts without a problem.

Today, after restart, Windows did a diagnosis and said,

```
Windows couldn't load correctly.
    Restore to an earlier time.
    Shut down your computer.
```

I chose to **Restore**.

After three minutes it said:

```
Automatic repair couldn't repair your computer.
Logfile: C:\Windows\System32\logfiles\srt\srtTrail.txt
    Continue...
    Use a device...
    Troubleshoot...
    Shutdown....
```

I chose to **Continue**, and it just worked, and here I am on SuperUser.

I am a developer not a system administrator. How do I go about debugging / fixing this?

## Log & Dump Files

**Dump File**

C:\Windows\Minidump\020514-14312-01.dmp

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17522409/020514-14312-01.dmp

**SrtTrail File**

C:\Windows\System32\logfiles\srt\srtTrail.txt

> Startup Repair diagnosis and repair log
>   --------------------------- Last successful boot time: ‎2/‎5/‎2014 5:29:17 PM (GMT) Number of repair attempts: 1
>
> Session details
>   --------------------------- System Disk = \Device\Harddisk0 Windows directory = C:\WINDOWS AutoChk Run = 0 Number of root causes = 1
>
> Test Performed: 
>   --------------------------- Name: Check for updates Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms
>
> Test Performed: 
>   --------------------------- Name: System disk test Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms
>
> Test Performed: 
>   --------------------------- Name: Disk failure diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms
>
> Test Performed: 
>   --------------------------- Name: Disk metadata test Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms
>
> Test Performed: 
>   --------------------------- Name: Target OS test Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 8500 ms
>
> Test Performed: 
>   --------------------------- Name: Volume content check Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 110 ms
>
> Test Performed: 
>   --------------------------- Name: Boot manager diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms
>
> Test Performed: 
>   --------------------------- Name: System boot log diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms
>
> Test Performed: 
>   --------------------------- Name: Event log diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 125 ms
>
> Test Performed: 
>   --------------------------- Name: Internal state check Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms
>
> Test Performed: 
>   --------------------------- Name: Boot status test Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 15 ms
>
> Test Performed: 
>   --------------------------- Name: Setup state check Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 125 ms
>
> Test Performed: 
>   --------------------------- Name: Registry hives test Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 1391 ms
>
> Test Performed: 
>   --------------------------- Name: Windows boot log diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms
>
> Test Performed: 
>   --------------------------- Name: Bugcheck analysis Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 141 ms
>
> Root cause found: 
>   --------------------------- A recent driver installation or upgrade may be preventing the system from starting.
>
> Repair action: System Restore Result: Failed. Error code =  0x1f Time
>   taken = 148125 ms

Comment: Your system administrator will have to solve the problem.  You have not supplied enough information and are unliekly going to have the capability to do so because of the lack of administrator permissions.

Comment: give me the dmp files from C:\Windows\Minidump, I'll look at them with Windbg.